# Formatted email in html

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have an html like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt;background:white">
        <b><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff6600">My Text</span></b>
           <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232"><u></u><u></u></span>
        </p>

        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232;background:white">My Text</span>
            <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232">
            <br>
            <span style="background:white">My Text</span>
            <br><span style="background:white">My Text</span><br>
            <span style="background:white">My Text</span><br>
            <span style="background:white">My Text<u></u><u></u></span></span>
        </p>
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt">
            <b><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff6600">My Text</span></b><br />
            <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232">%@<u></u><u></u></span>
        </p>
           <p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt">
           <b>
               <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff6600">My Text</span></b><br />
                <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232">My Text<u></u><u></u></span><br />
        </p>

        <p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:13.5pt;background:white">
            <b><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#ff6600">My Text</span></b>
        </p>

        <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232">My Text</span><br/>
        <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232">My Text</span><br/>
        <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:#323232">7My Text</span><br/><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works fine in my browser (Google Chrome). ("correct.png")

When a use this html to send a formatted email with my iOS application, the result is not the same when receiving the mail in my computer. ("NotCorrect.png").

How can à resolve this ? thanks

[image: correct]
[image: Not correct]

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert different browser webkits:

***Supported by Internet Explorer with the prefix -ms-***

***Supported by Firefox with the prefix -moz-***

***Supported by Google Chrome with the prefix -webkit-***

***Supported by Safari with the prefix -webkit-***

***Supported by Opera with the prefix -webkit-***

I recommend you add a style sheet because it makes your code a lot harder to read and assess

Safari is the iOS browser

Comment: can you give me an example how to insert one prefix ? Tnaks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

heres a list of browser support for them but an example would be

        `-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;`
        `-moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;`
        `border-top-right-radius: 20px;`

Comment: they're just examples though they aren't specific to your problem